# API after ship.com CORS JavaScript Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cors, phonegap

it's my first post here.

I have problem with send data by POST method.

console shows me that : 
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

I read about CORS but I have still the same problem.

Here is my code:

```
function track() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.aftership.com/v4/trackings/', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('aftership-api-key', 'key');

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(' works? : ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
        else {
            console.log('DOESN NOT WORK!' + xhr.status);
        }
    }
    xhr.send("tracking_number=number");
    //xhr.send();
}
```

Sometimes using GET method I can create tracking number but it doesn't work on long way. But when create it, I can use DELETE method with CORS plugin at Google Chrome. without plugin I can't use DELETE method.

I would to write for myself an application on phonegap using API aftership.

Please help! :D

Comment: I think this is a limitation of using the in-web-browser simulator for phonegap- the browser enforces CORS. It wouldn't be a problem on a real mobile device. From what I can tell, the usual solution suggested online is to configure your server to send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`. Obviously you can't do that if you don't control the API server, so I'm not sure what the solution is.

Comment: Your paragraph after the code is a bit unclear- if you have a plugin for Chrome that makes your code work(this plugin? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en), then that is fine. CORS is only really an issue when you are testing in the browser, so you can use that plugin there to get around it for testing.

Comment: Yes, I use this plugin but POST method still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your content security policy meta tag.

This line in the top of your HTML file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Can be changed to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

Notice the change in default-src. With the * there it allows any traffic so you could change that to your specific URL.

You could delete that meta tag completely. However this is unsafe and should only be done to see if that is causing your issue.

Read the section on Content Security Policy here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

You may also have a whitelist issue but try this first. If needed I will explain the whitelisting or you can read the link above.

Answer (score 0):

meta tag and whitelist plugin added

to config.xml added:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

still POST method doesn't work...

maybe is it easier way to use POST method by PHP or node.js?

I need resolve this problem to finish my app :(

Comment: Did you get it?